# Include a text file as a paragraph

Tags: include

I am trying to input a text file to latex. However, this text file contains special symbols like % and & which causes issues. I do not want to import the file as verbatim, it should be imported like regular text with paragraph formatting and word wrap.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14344/15925 help?

Comment: Or, if you are willing to use luaTeX https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48425/5404

Comment: @AndrewSwann It does, though that question is about verbatim, maybe we should copy the answer to here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimal approach:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\inputtextfile{}
\newcommand\redefinecharacter{}
\protected\def\redefinecharacter#1#2%
  {%
    \catcode`#1=13
    \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{#2}}%
  }
\protected\def\inputtextfile#1%
  {%
    \begingroup
    \redefinecharacter{\\}{\textbackslash}%
    \redefinecharacter{\{}{\{}%
    \redefinecharacter{\}}{\}}%
    \redefinecharacter{\$}{\$}%
    \redefinecharacter{\&}{\&}%
    \redefinecharacter{\#}{\#}%
    \redefinecharacter{\^}{\^{}}%
    \redefinecharacter{\_}{\_}%
    \redefinecharacter{\%}{\%}%
    \redefinecharacter{\~}{\textasciitilde}%
    \input{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
The output of our file doesn't look too good, because we input something that
contains code as text :)

\inputtextfile{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Ugly output:

[image]